# Cannot request an increased API Reads Per User Per Seconed - Google Website error?

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, rate-limiting

I keep getting errors from the Google API telling me that I have exceeded the limit of 100 reads per second per user when trying to read from Google Sheets using the API.  I'm using CozyRoc's REST Connection and REST Source connected to Google Sheets then connecting to a SQL Server Destination table and trying to populate the table from the Google Sheet.

Please don't try to offer any suggestions about other programs or other ways of accessing the data.  I have scores of SSIS packages that use the same set up to import data.  **In all of those that cycle through about 10 Google sheets with anywhere from one to 20 tabs and as many as 400 rows, I've had to set the Reads per Second to one to avoid the error.**  That makes my uploads incredibly slow. And YES, I contacted CozyRoc who tells me it's a Google API problem, not theirs, and there's nothing they can or will do about it.

So . . .  I made sure we have a billing account . . .

I was able to sign in and look at the Quotas screen.  500 reads per Second and 100 Reads per Second per user.

I was able to request an increased limit for the Reads Per Second to 500 which doesn't require a billing account, but that doesn't change the Reads Per Second Per User.

CozyRoc uses my user id (oAuth token) to access Google Sheets, so every read only comes from one user.

A popup displays when I try to edit the Reads Per Second Per User from the Quotas screen asking me to set the limit to a maximum of 100 or to request a quota limit increase.

I click on that request button and I am immediately returned to the Quotas screen.  I'm never asked to set a new limit, I'm never told that the request was sent and received, and I see no notice telling me how long it may take to process the request.  It's been about a week now since I first tried.  It would be nice if they would tell you SOMETHING!

My thought is that there may be something wrong with their website, perhaps with that popup.  I've tried calling Cloud Support, but they refuse to help, saying basically "Not my job to help you with setting quota limits," even though my question is really whether there is a known issue with the quota limit increase website/popup.

SO . . . Is anyone else having a similar problem?

Can anyone tell me if what's happening is normal and that it just takes WEEKS for Google to process a quota limit increase or how long it normally takes for them to process a quota limit rate increase?

Is there anywhere I can reach out to at Google where I can do a screen sharing session and show them what's happening to get an answer or find out whether or not my request was even received?

Any ideas or thoughts as to how I can find out what's going on?

Please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide additional information by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63649615/edit) your question rather than providing a new solution. From your description I cannot understand either you are trying to edit quotas in the correct way. I will post an answer explaining about the proccess to change quota and hope that this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

### How to edit API specific quota

- The user per minute quota can be edited API and project specific
- Go to the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
- Chose the project for which you want to icnrease the quota limit
- Go on`IAM & Admin -> Quotas`
  [image]
- Choose `Google Sheets API` and `Read reuquests`
- Click on the pencil next to `Read requests per 100 seconds per user`
- Choose a quota limit of below 100 - which is the maimum limit allowed by the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits)
- Click on Save

### If you want to increase your limit above 100 requests per 100 seconds per user:

- Mind that this limit is the above the normally alloweed quota
- Click on `apply for higher quota`

---

[image]

---

- Click on `ALL QUOTA` for `Read requests per 100 seconds per user`

---

[image]

---

- Check the toickbox next to `GLOBAL`

---

[image]

---

- Confirm your contact details and click on `Next`

---

[image]

---

- Enter the desire new limit and click on `Done`

---

[image]

**KEEP IN MIND**

- **If you do not have a billing account, you are not eligible to chose a limit of more than 100 read requests for user per 100 seconds and you will get the error message**

`You can't request more quota because your project is not linked to a billing account.`

---

[image]

---